# Memory leaks on 10.5 says no autorelease pool in place even though I do have?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa/xcode and I am writing a cocoa app in Xcode 4.3.2 
My target is 10.5 and base SDK is 10.7. I have to support 10.5 onwards.

I have used manual memory management and the app works fine on 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9. It also appears to work on 10.6.

On 10.5 (I don't have the system but from a report)

I am getting lots of these errors,

```
Oct 22, 2013 3:44:08 PM: *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1126f49b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x7fff823a11e8 0x7fff822b9771 0x10002cfb0 0x10002bc19 0x10002add1 0x7fff822bfd35 0x7fff8467ed0f 0x7fff8467ebd1)
Oct 22, 2013 3:44:08 PM: *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1126f4c90 of class NSCFSet     autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x7fff823a11e8 0x7fff822b9771 0x7fff82315748 0x10002bc52 0x10002add1 0x7fff822bfd35 0x7fff8467ed0f 0x7fff8467ebd1)
```

In my code I have used autoreleasepools for threads other than main thread

```
@autoreleasepool
{
  //whatever code calling autorelease on objects..  
}
```

For main thread I have not provided any pool assuming it is automatically provided. I am wondering if the above errors are because the autoreleasepool blocks are not compatible  with 10.5 ? Or possibly my assumption about main thread autorelease pool is automatically provided even for 10.5 is incorrect ? This is correct at least for 10.7 onwards. I am not sure what's going on with 10.5.

Any suggestions would be great..

Comment: The `main()` generated by the Xcode templates always has an `@autoreleasepool`...

Comment: well the message can hardly be wrong ;) so you are in some thread lacking a pool (that you created: not GCD)

Answer (score 0):

`@autorelease{}` blocks are a feature that were introduced with ARC - which postdates 10.5.

In pre-ARC days, you would have used this construction:

```
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.

  [pool release];
```

...which is still perfectly valid with non-ARC code on all system versions.

**update**

This answer has generated some debate (see below). When the compiler sees an `@autorelease{}` block it uses it to generate the above `NSAutoreleasePool` non-block construction, so there should be no version compatibility issues. *However*, blocks themselves are a feature only available from 10.6 onwards. So - although the documentation is thin on this point - I would be fairly certain that this is the  cause of the problem.

Lacking a 10.5 setup, I cannot test. Perhaps someone else can confirm?

**update 2**
I seem to have got most of this wrong (not the first time!).

Here is a nugget of info [from the Clang docs' introduction of `@autoreleasepool`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#autoreleasepool):

> To simplify the use of autorelease pools, and to bring them under the control of the compiler, a new kind of statement is available in Objective-C. It is written @autoreleasepool followed by a compound-statement, i.e. by a new scope delimited by curly braces. Upon entry to this block, the current state of the autorelease pool is captured. When the block is exited normally, whether by fallthrough or directed control flow (such as return or break), the autorelease pool is restored to the saved state, releasing all the objects in it. When the block is exited with an exception, the pool is not drained.
>
> @autoreleasepool may be used in non-ARC translation units, with equivalent semantics.

and especially...

> > A program is ill-formed if it refers to the NSAutoreleasePool class.

So we should *not* directly address NSAutoreleasePool since the introduction of `@autorelease{}`

I will leave this wrong answer up for now as the comments have been enlightening.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler fabricate those `NSAutoreleasePool` calls when it sees `@autoreleasepool` and ARC isn't being used?

Comment: @trojanfoe - Only on the main thread. I am assuming this issues are occurring because the relevant process is on a background thread.

Comment: I don't believe that's true; the docs certainly don't make it obvious and it would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @trojanfoe - From the docs: "If you are making Cocoa calls outside of the Application Kit’s main thread—for example if you create a Foundation-only application or if you detach a thread—you need to create your own autorelease pool."

Comment: You misunderstand me; You can use `@autoreleasepool` instead of `NSAutoreleasePool` in both ARC and non-ARC code and main and non-main threads.

Comment: `@autoreleasepool` ==> `NSAutoreleasePool`

Comment: @trojanfoe - you are right, i misunderstood your comments. In fact my answer _might_ be about to self-destruct!

Comment: @trojanfoe - i didn't hit the self-destruct button, but I have updated my answer, perhaps you could take a look.

Comment: According to Greg Parker: ["If your deployment target is too old for the new optimized autorelease pool implementation, the compiler will call the traditional NSAutoreleasePool methods instead."](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/309906-blocks-vs-life-the-universe-and-everything.html)

Comment: Not so sure what you mean by *blocks*; I think you are confusing *blocks* (as in the Apple-introduced-closure-type-feature) with plain ol' `{ ...}`.  Also the keyword is `@autoreleasepool` and not `@autorelease`.

Comment: Also I think the OP answered his own question; he's made an assumption that an auto-release pool is in place on the main thread, which isn't true.

Comment: @trojanfoe My assumption was based on this statement from the apple documentation "The AppKit and UIKit frameworks process each event-loop iteration (such as a mouse down event or a tap) within an autorelease pool block. Therefore you typically do not have to create an autorelease pool block yourself, or even see the code that is used to create one. There are, however, three occasions when you might use your own autorelease pool blocks:" source https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: @trojanfoe, how would that explain the different behaviour in 10.5 vs the rest? (+ I have updated my non-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add a symbolic breakpoint for `NSAutoreleaseNoPool()` (see the [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/68421) if you're unfamiliar how to do this). This will put you into the debugger when you create an object this way, which will tell you exactly what thread you're having trouble with.